Downloading a PDF using puppeteer giving 403 error
I am trying to download a pdf to my tmp folder using puppeteer but i was ending up with a 403 error. the target link opens nicely on a browser, no auth or captchas or anything. i am not sure what i am doing wrong here.
const downloadPDFViaProxy = async (url: string, outputPath: string) => {
  console.log('Using Proxy');
  const proxyChain = require('proxy-chain');

  const oldProxyUrl = 'http://username:password@hostname:8000';
  const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);
  // console.log(newProxyUrl);

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-infobars',
      '--window-position=0,0',
      '--ignore-certifcate-errors',
      '--ignore-certifcate-errors-spki-list',
    ],
    headless: true,
    // executablePath: '/opt/homebrew/bin/chromium',
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  });
  var userAgent = require('user-agents');

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent(userAgent.random().toString());

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  console.log('reached here');
  // const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  //   args: [
  //     '--no-sandbox',
  //     '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  //     '--proxy-server=http://66.29.154.105:3128', // Specify your proxy server here
  //   ],
  // });
  // const page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot_new1.png' });

    await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
      timeout: 60000, // 60 seconds
    });
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot_new2.png', fullPage: true });

    const pdfUrl = await page.evaluate(() => document.location.href);

    // Use Puppeteer built-in download mechanism instead of fetch
    const response = await page.goto(pdfUrl);
    if (!response || !response.ok()) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to download PDF. Status: ${response.status()}`);
    }

    // Save PDF to file system
    const pdfBuffer = await response.buffer();
    fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, pdfBuffer);
    console.log(`PDF downloaded successfully to: ${outputPath}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
};


i have tried multiple things as of now. randomizing user agents using proxies, giving timeouts what not. but none seem to work. with the code that i posted, it gives me a timeout error. my download file is 5-6 MB. Any help would be much appreciated.

Can you share the site? I assume not since there's auth involved, but it's pretty hard to help otherwise, unfortunately.

Using axios alone from node.js would be faster and more reliable than using puppeteer to do so (unless you absolutely must use puppeteer for whatever reason).
Also, use networkidle2 to make sure the page is fully loaded before the download takes place.

my first option is fetch function from node.js but it gives me a 403 hence pupeteer
